# Obtaining mixand weights from gmdistribution in matlab

Tags: matlab, gaussian

From what I can tell, MATLAB 2016a does not have a way to obtain the mixand weights from a gmdistribution object. Is that correct?

It seems strange that the constructor calls for the weights, but no property or method exists to extract them again. In other words:

myGM = gmdistribution(means, covariances, weights);

myWeights = myGM.(???)

Am I missing something here? I'd hate to define a new class just to add a weights property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does have a way to retrieve them. You just call `myGM.ComponentProportion`. See the [gmdistribution class documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution-class.html) for more properties you can query.

Comment: Man, that's some poorly named variables. My brain must have skimmed that 10 times and not realized what it is! Thanks